# JSTL not recognized in JSP after adding jar

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I added jstl-1.2.jar to my lib folder, then I included:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

on top of my JSP file and still It says `Unknown tag (c:forEach).

**welcome.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <c:forEach>
 </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

[Project construction HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRMlU.png)

Comment: You need the standard.jar as well.  I'd recommend learning how to use Maven.  It'll manage your dependencies for you.

Comment: I have the dependency there. I just restart my Eclipse and it is fixed now. Lol. Feeling stupid now ...

Comment: I'd also recommend using IntelliJ.  It's a better IDE than Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Use only jstl-1.2.jar

2.Try to get some items to iterate, for example:

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.list}" var="item">
</c:forEach>
```